# Unexpected behavior with expressions and statements in macros

Tags: c

If I run this code i am getting the output as 5 3 which I understand as if condition is satisfied and the numbers are getting swapped here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define big(a,b) a>b?a:b
#define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
int main()
{
    int a=3,b=5,temp;
    if ((3+big(a,b)>b)){
        swap(a,b);
    }
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

But if remove the bracket and put it after `(3+big(a,b))>b` I am getting the output as 3 5 the numbers are not getting swapped which i am not understanding here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define big(a,b) a>b?a:b
#define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
int main() 
{
    int a=3,b=5,temp;
    if ((3+big(a,b))>b){
        swap(a,b);
    }
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore if I remove the flower brackets in the `if` condition then I am getting the output as 5 0 here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define big(a,b) a>b?a:b
#define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
int main() 
{
    int a=3,b=5,temp;
    if ((3+big(a,b))>b)
        swap(a,b);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone give a detailed explanation for why is this happening?

Comment: Look at the preprocessor output - the explanation will be obvious.

Comment: Macros do text replacement on your code. If you do that replacement manually yourself, you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Some flavour of this question has been asked by literally everyone learning C before you... surely we must have hundreds of duplicate questions on SO.

Comment: Also "macros are text replacement" is the standard answer but an over-simplification. You can't just pass any text to them, you have to pass valid tokens. Also there's lots of special cases like expansion, stringification, token concatenation, string literal concatenation etc etc. My best advise is to read about it all in a C programming book.

Comment: @Lundin can you suggest me a book which contains all the topics mentioned above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros perform direct text token substitution.  So this:

```
(3+big(a,b))>b
```

Expands to this:

```
(3+a>b?a:b)>b
```

Which parses like this due to operator precedence:

```
((3+a)>b?a:b)>b
```

Which is not what you want.  This is why macros expressions (and their arguments) should be parenthesized:

```
#define big(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

On a side note, you can't pass an expression with side effects like `a++` to such a macro as doing so will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to a value being updated more than once unsequenced in an expression.

There is a similar problem with the `swap` macro as used here:

```
if ((3+big(a,b))>b)
    swap(a,b);
```

Which expands to this:

```
if ((3+big(a,b))>b)
    temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
```

So that only `temp=a;` is part of the "if" condition while the rest is outside the statement.  This can be fixed by putting the body of this macro in a `do` loop:

```
#define swap(a,b) do { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; } while (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros work by textual substitution.

This

```
  if (foo) {
    swap(a,b);
  }
```

will be compiled as

```
  if (foo) {
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
  }
```

Whereas this

```
  if (foo)
    swap(a,b);
```

will be compiled as

```
  if (foo)
    temp=a;

  a=b;
  b=temp;
```

That should make it clear enough.

Disclaimer: in order to make the actual code seen by the compiler more readable, I added line breaks and indentations.

Overall conclusion: don't use macros for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are very tricky as they are not functions only perform ***text*** (more precisely token)  replacement. It is done before the C code is actually compiled

```
#define big(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define swap(a,b, type) do{ type temp=(a); (a)=(b); (b)=temp;} while (0)
```

You need to use parenthesises and remember that  side effects will ruin your macro behaviour. Example:

```
int a = 5, b = 6;
printf("%d\n", big(a++, b));
swap(b++,a,int);
```

will invoke undefined behaviour as it will be expanded to `((a++)>(b)?(a++):(b));` or `do{ int temp=(b++); (b++)=(a); (a)=temp;} while (0);`